# IsDBNul with string

Tags: c#, mysqldatareader

I try to use

```
currentOrder.PONumber = (reader.IsDBNull("PONumber") ? "Geen klantreferentie" : reader.GetString("PONumber"));
```

and I have the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.IsDBNull(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments.

and

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'.

When I use the columnindex in `IsDBNull`, I have the following error:

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you share the code for when you use the column index, as that's the way the documentation says to use it?

Comment: It sounds to me like your currentOrder.PONumber property is an int and you are trying to assign strings to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("PONumber"))
```

Or if you are iterating many rows, keep hold of the ordinal and re-use it:

```
var poNumberOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("PONumber");

while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.IsDBNull(poNumberOrdinal);
}
```

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I do it only one time.

Comment: @MartenB Ok then simply using it as shown will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
currentOrder.PONumber = reader["PONumber"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 
                         "Geen klantreferentie" :  reader.GetString("PONumber"));
```